# Permanently turn off contribution-like notifications in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Why am I seeing (from time to time) contribution-like notifications / suggestions:

[image]

if I have disabled them:

[image]

I don't want to contribute, I don't want to be annoyed with these notifications and want to get rid of them once and for good. How to disable them *permanently*, if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

To disable those messages, open Maps and then swipe in from the left side to open the app menu. Select “Settings,” then “Notification.” Finally, tap on “Your contributions,” and then switch off “Questions about places.”

Comment: This is web apps, so questions and answers should be about the web interface. There'll be no "swiping" with a web browser.

Comment: @ale You're true about the topic, however... on the other side, I wouldn't be very surprised, if it turned out that you can disable maps notifications in desktop using mobile interface only. It's Google, right? Anything is possible! :>

Comment: @trejder I think that if that's the case, for the answer to be good - it should state that the option is available only in the mobile app and not in the web app, and not just jump to an explanation on the mobile app where we don't know if it's possible in the web app

Comment: In addition to above comments I must admit that I have followed Ganesh' suggestions and it turned out to be not quite what I am looking for. Similarly to my question I have **everything** (and I mean everything, every knob) switched off and yet, I'm still seeing those pesky notifications (in both mobile and desktop Maps) from time to time.